# PHP PDO loop different in JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo

I'm trying to make a loop to add all POST keys to PDO bind Parameter.
when i make the POST Request with JS it works however if i made it all in php it don't which i found kind of a strange ,here's an example .

This the JS

```
 var dataString="Name="+encodeURIComponent($("#name ."+Name[i]+"").val())+"&Email="+encodeURIComponent($("#email ."+Name[i]+"").val());
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendback.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
     }
    });
```

PHP Backend.

```
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $Value=trim(urldecode($value));
       $stmt -> bindParam(':'.$key.'',$Value);
    }
```

Result

```
---------------------------
Name          |        Email 
AAA           |email@exa.com
----------------------------
```

This Works and stores data correctly in the database

However

This Don't

```
$_POST['Name']="AAA";
$_POST['Email']="email@exa.com";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$Value=trim(urldecode($value));
$stmt -> bindParam(':'.$key.'',$Value);
}
$stmt -> execute();
```

Result

```
---------------------------
Name          |        Email 
email@exa.com |email@exa.com
----------------------------
```

It stores the values of the last $_post key in all the database columns . 
So all the inputs to the database in this example would be "email@exa.com"
after searching i found that to make the previous example works i need to add an "&" before the "$value" in the loop,makes me wonder why it's different than the Ajax request,i mean they both POST requests,right?

Comment: `var dataString={name1: val1, name2: val2,........}`

Comment: In what way does it not work??

Comment: in the last example when i try to make the $POST with PHP it self rather than an Ajax request

Comment: Yes but in what way does it not work?

Comment: Oh , sorry about that I didn't mention the results .

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Do you have a print_r of $_POST in both cases before you loop it?

Comment: This is in Case 1 
Array ( [Name] => AAccA [Email] => exam@ea.com )
This is in Case 2 
Array ( [Name] => AAccA [Email] => exam@ea.com )

weird enough now in both cases the database inputs are wrong , 
they insert the value of email in both fields . i think i'm going to retest to locate the issue

Answer (score 1):

What the PDO docs fail to explain is that `bindParam()` is passed to PDO byref - whereas `bindValue()` isn't.

It's better to use `bindValue()` in this case. `bindParam()` is intended to execute a query, and then change the variables and re-execute without binding the parameters again. `bindValue()` binds immediately, `bindParam()` only on execute

`&$value` is the reference to the `$value`, not it's value

Comment: This doesn't change anything compared to his own code. Besides that, it would crash his file since you have two errors in your code. There are too much quotes before the mail and you have a comma too much at the end.